# WatchKit Interface - contentSafeAreaInsets and systemMinimumLayoutMargins zero

Tags: swift, swift5

In my watchkit interface controller script I'm trying to get the content safe area, but it always results in all the data being zero...

```
let margin = self.systemMinimumLayoutMargins
print(margin)
//prints: NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, leading: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, trailing: 0.0)

let inset = self.contentSafeAreaInsets
print(inset)
//prints: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

I'm building to the series 5 simulator. Tried both the 40mm and 44mm with the same result. My Interface.storyboard is set to Full Screen since I'm doing a spriteKit scene... Is there any way to get the actual system margins/insets for the curved displays?